# Connecting to my SQL Server database with Visual Web Developer 2008 express

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-web-developer

The problem I'm having is that I have created a database in SQL Server Management Studio, but when I try to add a connection to it in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express I get the following error:

> You do not have permission to use this file. Please contact the file owner to obtain permission.

I use Windows authentication so I'm not sure how it doesn't register me as the owner of the file. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Where is the database server located? (and why are you using VS2008?)

Comment: It's for a course, it's an old textbook and that's what they suggested so i used it to match up with the examples. The database server is in the same folder that i have put my web app.

Comment: A file is not a "database server" - I mean the running instance of SQL Server. Is it on the same computer? Is it SQL Server Express or SQL Server LocalDB or some other SKU?

Comment: SQL server express, on my local computer.